# JsonLinesItemExporter outputs an array in each field

Tags: scrapy, jsonlines

I'm using JsonLinesItemExporter to export some data and instead of

```
{"name": "Color TV", "price": "1200"}
{"name": "DVD player", "price": "200"}
```

scrapy is writing the following to file:

```
{"name": ["Color TV"], "price": ["1200"]}
{"name": ["DVD player"], "price": ["200"]}
```

(From debug) it seems I'm passing a correct value (not a list) and that both `item.add_value` and `item.replace_value` are replacing my strings by a single string element list.

Is this configurable?
If not, how to get a different behaviour? Extend `JsonLinesItemExporter` or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you're using properly configured ItemLoader?
I'de recommend to use `TakeFirst` (documentation here: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html)

Example of usage:

```
class YourItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()
```

Comment: That's right! Hadn't even configured that! But I can't find documentation about the default processors.